# mysql grouping of records based on order

Tags: mysql

I have the following records created under `contact_details` mysql table.

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|data_ref_id| data_value  | data_order |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|ref001     | Alex        |        001 |
|ref001     | 040-345-234 |        002 |
|ref002     | Adam        |        001 |
|ref002     | 040-225-254 |        002 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

How to fetch records in below format?

```
+------+-------------+
| Alex | 040-345-234 |
| Adam | 040-225-254 |
+------+-------------+
```

Comment: What column are you planning to use for `order` as there is no guarantee that the output will be displayed in same order as you have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Similary to what @Utsav is saying - how do you know which number is supposed to line up with Adam, and which with Alex. If this is still early in the project you should consider a change in your data model.

Comment: wierd question there is no relation what so ever between Alex 040-345-234 and Adam 040-225-254

Comment: Corrected the data with column **data_ref_id**

Comment: @GratusD.: updated the question with additional column to get more clarity -  **data_ref_id**

Comment: You could try joining the table to itself to get the info from the 2nd record. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data_order` is always `001` and `002` then you can use something like this.

```
select t1.data_value as name,t2.data_value as phone
from your_table t1
inner join your_table t2
on t1.data_ref_id=t2.data_ref_id
and t1.data_order='001'
and t2.data_order='002'
```